# Dynamic VLANs with FreeRadius, OpenLDAP & Cisco WLC

Tags: cisco, openldap, freeradius, dynamic-vlan-assignment

Currently have a FreeRADIUS 1.1.6 server authenticating users from OpenLDAP which are stored in the *posixAccount* account schema. We've now installed a Cisco WLC, and want to authenticate those users over 802.1X (which is successfully working), but also dynamically assign their computer onto a VLAN based on the MAC address of that computer (we're also using certificates, so the problems of MAC spoofing should be pretty much mitigated).

I've imported the radius schema into OpenLDAP, and have created a *cn* called **dot1x**, and based it on the objectClass *radiusprofile* - so we have an entry like this:

```
dn:cn=machine-1146,cn=dot1x,dc=org,dc=com
cn: machine-1146
radiusTunnelMediumType: IEEE-802
radiusTunnelType: VLAN
radiusTunnelPrivateGroupId: 600
objectClass: radiusprofile
objectClass: top
```

The questions are

- Where in *cn=dot1x,dc=org,dc=com* do we put the MAC address of the machine?
- How do I configure FreeRADIUS to search *ou=people* for user authentication, and then *cn=dot1x* for the computer MAC address, and then respond with the *radiusTunnelPrivateGroupId*?

Thanks for your help!